# PowerQuery Table Transformation

Tags: powerquery

I want to be able to make the first column in my table pair with all others, making a new row for every combination of the two.

I need to be able to turn this:

- A | 1 | 2 | 3
- B | 4 | 5 | 6
- C | 6 | 7 | 9

Into this:

- A | 1
- A | 2
- A | 3
- B | 4
- B | 5
- B | 6
- C | 7
- C | 8
- C | 9

Is there any way this can be done using just powerquery?

Answer (score 0):

Just unpivot other columns:

```
unpivot = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"col1"}, "a", "b")[[col1],[b]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Are they in separate columns? Then load into powerquery, right click first column, choose unpivot other columns.

Are they in a single column separated by |s? Then use below

Right click column, split column by delimiter, Select or enter delimeter --Custom-- |, Split at each occurrence of the delimiter, ignore advanced options

Remove the latter part of the query so that
    = Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type", "Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Column1.1", "Column1.2", "Column1.3", "Column1.4"}),

becomes
    = Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type", "Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.Csv))

right Click first Column, unpivot other columns

right Click attribute column, remove column

Assuming data is in Table1 with no column headers or header column of Column1 then code is

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type", "Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.Csv)),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Split Column by Delimiter", {"Column1.1"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Attribute"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```